# Find a value in the list

Tags: python, list, search

I need to find the value 2022. Then, if the value in the list is found, I need to store it in a variable as Dresden 2022

test = ['Berlin 2020', 'Dresden 2022', 'Hamburg 2021'].

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the list and then check each item:

```
value = None
for item in test:
    if '2022' in item:
        value = item
if value:  # Found something with 2022
    # Do something with value
```

Comment: how can I save Dresden 2022 if the value 2022 is found?

Comment: `value` stores "Dresden 2022".